# presence detection using Panasonic grid eye

Tags: detection, motion

I want to use grid eye AMG8833 for presence detection. Has anyone used gridEye for the same purpose? 
Or 
Can someone suggest algorithms to decide whether someone is present beneath the sensor or not ?

Comment: What is AMG8331? If I google it, the only relevant search results that show up are your questions on different question sites.
EDIT: Now I see you're referring to Panasonic AMG88 sensor. There is no 8x3 pixel unit (ref. the numbering scheme).

Comment: sorry for naming it wrong. It's AMG 8833, a thermal sensor by Panasonic

Comment: Then edit your post to represent the correct name. You cant expect people to guess what you mean.

Please also be aware that Stack Exchange is not a free design house at your disposal. What are your initial ideas ideas for solving this? This question seems to be too broad and opinion based as it is worded right now. Reformulate the question to something with a specific answer, and I have a feeling you will attract more productive answers.

Comment: could that be AMG8833? https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Panasonic%20Sensors%20PDFs/Grid-EYE_AMG88.pdf  Did you not understand the datasheet?

Comment: @MrGerber, I was not aware of the type of the questions that should be asked at this forum, certainly will be taken care onwards.Apart from that, I think GridEye by Panasonic is a renowned sensor. I do have implemented a number of ideas to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth.  This is a thousand words.

https://www.anglia-live.com/angliaCust/ldp/pdf/Application%20Note%20(White%20Paper)%20150925_Grid-EYE%E6%A1%88_R3.pdf

[image]

code examples are worth even more

http://docplayer.net/54576058-C-source-code-for-general-use.html

Comment: these are just datasheet of the sensor of which I'm already familiar.

Comment: so you have it working?

Comment: Can you display sensor images?  If so pls share and read https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c7d/cf8dce7438ef682d516063f8fd66b42acfd9.pdf